# Click on cell, Have range of data display through linked picture

Tags: excel, vba

First time posting, hope this all makes sense. I have created a graphic in excel that shows 88 lines [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ratWP.png). In another worksheet there are rows of data documented what is on each line [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atHsu.png) When a line is clicked on the graphic I want the corresponding data from the other worksheet to pop up [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3YnF.png)

I have managed it achieve this by making a transparent button/shape over each line to hide and show a linked image [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Wws.png). However, I've had to create a separate button and macro for each line with 100+ lines this seems every inefficient. this is the code I used :

```
Sub LINE1A1()

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 9").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
        If .Text = "Hide" Then
            .Text = "Show"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = False
        Else
            .Text = "Hide"
            With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 9")
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Left = .Left + .Width
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Top = .Top + .Height
                ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 3").Visible = True
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

What would be a better way to achieve this? side not I used linked image as the data and range of data is subject to changes as each line could have more than 1 row of data.

Comment: Which item is "Rectangle 9"?  I also don't see any show/hide text in your screenshots.  How are the lines to be shown related to the clicked-on line?  Seems like there is a better way to do this if we had a bit more context.

Comment: My bad, So there is a transparent rectangle with text matching the colour of the cell (line) it is placed over so it is practically invisible. I will edit the main post with some more context. thanks for the reply @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0):

You can create those buttons or shapes with a macro (as you said for example 100 buttons) and move them with a macro so they are in the right place. They are going to use the same macro. It will just do a different thing depending where the button is or maybe better depending on its name.

There is a nice tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bF28JhlC7yc&index=18&list=PLpOAvcoMay5SE3XTp2YN2v6NcJuXKM9KX

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example where a common Sub uses `Application.Caller` to figure out which shape triggered it.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim s As Shape, c, s2 As Shape

    c = Application.Caller        '<< name of your clicked shape
    Debug.Print c

    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(c) '<< the clicked shape

    With s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters

        'here you need some way to transform the name of the clicked
        '  shape to get the name of the other shape to be shown/hidden/moved
        Set s2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes(c & "_linked")

        s2.Visible = (.Text = "Show")
        .Text = IIf(.Text = "Show", "Hide", "Show") 'toggle text

    End With

End Sub
```